# Thread loop in Ruby

Tags: ruby, multithreading, thread-safety

I have to work with a script that handle two parallel jobs.

The script basically wil have two loops:

```
loop do
  # do something
  sleep 5
end

loop do
  # do something else
  sleep 10
end
```

So, I thought to leave the first loop inside a Thread, so it runs side by side with the second loop.

I tried something like:

```
Thread.new do
  loop do
    # do something
    sleep 5
  end
end

loop do
  # do something else
  sleep 10
end
```

The first loop will read infos from Memcached (through Dalli Gem), and call another class to do some jobs, but it seems not work properlty, not the way I expected: The script locks and do not execute the code inside the thread.

The problem, i think its because I have a connection created before the two loops:

```
@connection = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.raw_connection
```

This connection is used by the first loop, inside the thread and by second loop.

So, there is a safe way to create this jobs to run simultaneously?

Thread is kind of a tabboo in my company and i am trying to change this :(

Thanks a lot!

Comment: > but it seems not work properlty, not the way I expected.
could you be more specific? What is going not the right way?

Comment: @nattfodd, sorry, added some more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Mutex](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Mutex.html) for this. The summary given there:

> Mutex implements a simple semaphore **that can be used to coordinate access to shared data from multiple concurrent threads**.

It's pretty simple to use, you just instantiate a Mutex and then call `synchronize` on it whenever you want to safely access the db:

```
require 'mutex'
semaphore = Mutex.new
Thread.new do
  loop do
    semaphore.synchronize do
      # do something
    end
    sleep 5
  end
end
```

Comment: Why the thread.new îs outside.of the loop? I think should be inside the loop since You want to syncronize between multiple threads but your code creates a single thread that runs indefinitely . So mutex.synchronize can't syncronize a single thread. Or maybe i am seeing it in a wrong way.

Comment: @RadaBogdan OP's question was about two different loops which should not block each other. I ommitted the other loop, which would also have thread and mutex#synchronize

Comment: Ahh yes. That makes sense

Comment: Thanks, did not know about this feature!